# Failed to read pids.max attribute of cgroup root, ignoring: No such file or directory

Tags: boot, systemd

Sometimes (not always) when I boot my pc to GNU/Linux Ubuntu an error appears for every mounted application.

(/var/log/syslog content)

```
Mar 27 11:40:53 jakub-B85M-D2V systemd[1]: Failed to read pids.max attribute of cgroup root, ignoring: No such file or directory
```

I'm not sure what causes it, but yet if it happens it boots successfully.

additional data:

OS: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS x86_64
Kernel: 5.4.0-66-generic
Shell: bash 5.0.17

Comment: Well, there is no cgroup pids.max for root, as the entry indicates. Typically this warning occurs when one does something as root that should be done as a regular user. Have a look at `ls -l /sys/fs/cgroup/pids/*/*/pids.max`.

Comment: currently it booted without the warnings and all pids.max files are here, should i try having luck and booting it with the warnings?

Comment: I think the files will be there either way. I suspect some sort of timing issue, but am not sure.